# Nameerror:name 'flowrate' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

here is my code. I am getting 'flowrate' not defined. while i have a function named flowrate. please help me!! thanks in advance.
its a name error: 'flowrate' not defined .
flowrate is the new function that i created

```
#flowrate module
f=flowrate(kro,uo,bo,krg,ug,bg,krw,uw,bw,rso,rsw,h,kx,ky,delx,dely,po)

def flowrate(kro,uo,bo,krg,ug,bg,krw,uw,bw,rso,rsw,h,kx,ky,delx,dely,po):
global index, nxt, nyt, welin, fmult    
import numpy as np 
qo=np.zeros(nxt,nyt)
qg=np.zeros(nxt,nyt)
ql=np.zeros(nxt,nyt)

yo=kro/(uo*bo);                                                           
yg=krg/(ug*bg)+rsw*(krw/(uw*bw))+rso*(kro/(uo*bo));                
yw=krw/(uw*bw);

qo(welin)=-20

qo=qo*fmult
qw=(qo*yw)/yo
qg=(qo*yg)/yo

return [qo ,qw ,qg]
```

Comment: It is because you are calling `f = flowrate(...)` before you have defined it.
Try moving `f = flowrate(...)` below the function definition.

Comment: flowrate function is saved in another file named flowrate and i use import flowrate before calling the function in main script

Comment: This is one reason why it's encouraged to not run code at the top level of a module; make a `main` method (whereever you like) and put `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` at the bottom. By placing the invocation of `main` at the bottom, you ensure the module has all classes/functions/global variables defined before trying to use them.

Comment: @PriyankSrivastava: You're not importing it with `import flowrate`; if you were, you'd have a different error (`TypeError` with message "module object is not callable" or the like, caused by trying to call the module, rather than the function within it). The `NameError` implies neither the function nor the module exists in your scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your module is named `flow_module` and your function is named `flow_function`.

`# Method 1: import the entire module and access function with module name
import flow_module
f = flow_module.flow_function(...)`

`# Method 2: import only the function from the module
from flow_module import flow_function
f = flow_function(...)`

Comment: I solved it by calling flowrate.flowrate from main program